# Cloud Dataproc error - "Failed to load" in GDC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to create a Dataproc cluster via the Google Developers Console (GDC), but keep getting the error "Failed to load" after clicking "Create Cluster".

1. Billing is enabled
2. Enabled APIs include Dataproc

Anybody know what I'm missing?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened the browser console and could see there were some permission problems with the Compute Engine API. Even though it was listed as being enabled in my project, it actually wasn't.

So I clicked on "`Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM Instances`" and then let it load. When it had finished "Initialising Compute Engine for project API project", I went back to the Dataproc section and I was able to create the cluster.

[image]